# problems with Euklides in java

Tags: java

I have some problems with java. All help are great for me. Here is the problem:

```
public class Fraction {

    private int numerator;
    private int denominator;

    // Konstruktor
    public Fraction(int numerator, int denominator) {
        this.numerator = numerator;
        this.denominator = numerator;
    }

    public int getTaljare() {
        return numerator;
    }

    public int getNamnare() {
        return denominator;
    }

    private int findSGD() {
        int rest = numerator % denominator;
        int restTwo = numerator % rest;
        int restThree = rest % restTwo;
        int restFour = restTwo % restThree;
        int restFive = restThree % restFour;
        if (numerator == denominator) {
            int m = numerator / denominator;
            return m;
        } else if (rest == 0) {
            int m = numerator / denominator;
            return m;
        } else if (restTwo == 0) {
            int m = numerator / denominator;
            return m;
        } else if (restThree == 0) {
            int m = numerator / denominator;
            return m;
        } else if (restFour == 0) {
            int m = numerator / denominator;
            return m;
        } else if (restFive == 0) {
            int m = numerator / denominator;
            return m;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int k = 0;
        if
    }
}
```

I am trying do this:
Create a class Fraction as a template for fractions. One fraction is the number of the form p / q where p and q are integers (q may not be 0). The class must contain
See note card file.

- Private member variables for the numerator and denominator (select the appropriate name and specify the type itself)
- A constructor that is used to specify initial values for the numerator and denominator when we create objects from our class.
- A public method getTaljare () that returns the value of the fraction numerator and a public method getNamnare () that returns the value of the denominator.
- A private method findSGD () that

  - Calculate the greatest common divisor of the numerator and denominator and returns it (see details on the greatest common divisor below).
    Tip: Distinguish between the cases numerator = denominator, the numerator> denominator and the denominator> numerator.
- A public method isSimplified () that

  - Determines if the fraction is shortened as much as possible or not. How do we know that? A fraction is shortened as much as possible about the greatest common divisor is 1, so this method need to call findSGD ().
  - Returns false if there is abbreviated as far as possible and true if it is abbreviated as far as possible.
- A public method Simplify () that

  - Shortens the row as far as possible and put the numerator and the denominator (member variables) to the abbreviated values. This is done by first checking if the fraction is shortened as much as possible (by calling isSimplified ()). If it is not, so it must be shortened by the numerator and denominator are divided by the greatest common divisor. So this method also needs to call findSGD ().

Comment: what did you try? Sounds like a CS exercise that you should figure out as part of the course.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Here's a few pointers for you: 1) We will not give you the full solution on a silver platter, since that wouldn't teach you anything. 2) In order to present a question, you need to have at least one sentence with a question mark, not just put in what's expected of your program in general and expect us to solve it for you. 3) In order to present a proper question, add in what you've done so far, what it's supposed to do and what it's doing that's different from what you want it to do.